# Changing mercury color in thermometer in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have created a thermometer chart with JFreeChart, but I want to change the mercury color in thermometer. How can I do this? Here is my code so far; please explain where to change this code:

```
final DefaultValueDataset dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(new Double(10));

// create the chart...
final ThermometerPlot plot = new ThermometerPlot(dataset);

final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Thermometer Demo 2",  // chart title
                                        JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,
                                        plot,                  // plot
                                        false);                // include legend

chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(241,250,224));
plot.setMercuryPaint();
final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setUpperBound(50);
```

Comment: Where's the code for `setMercuryPaint()`

Comment: that i tried but it's not working

Comment: I'm asking for the code of this method `setMercuryPaint()`

Comment: plot.setMercuryPaint(Color.red);
i used the above syntax but it's not changing the color to red

Comment: No. Please POST the code for `setMercuryPaint()`

Comment: @Mob: It's part of the `org.jfree.chart.plot.ThermometerPlot` class.

Comment: Alright. @praveen try `plot.setMercuryPaint(new Color(int,int,int));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be looking for [`setSubrangePaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ThermometerPlot.html#setSubrangePaint-int-java.awt.Paint-), demonstrated below.

[image: ThermometerDemo]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ThermometerPlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultValueDataset;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597015 */
public class ThermometerDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final int W = 200;
    private static final int H = 2 * W;

    public ThermometerDemo(double value) {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        DefaultValueDataset dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(value);
        ThermometerPlot plot = new ThermometerPlot(dataset);
        plot.setSubrangePaint(0, Color.green.darker());
        plot.setSubrangePaint(1, Color.orange);
        plot.setSubrangePaint(2, Color.red.darker());
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Demo",
            JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart, W, H, W, H, W, H,
            false, true, true, true, true, true));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
                f.add(new ThermometerDemo(40));
                f.add(new ThermometerDemo(60));
                f.add(new ThermometerDemo(80));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```