# Tank Level Indicator Image in Swing GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, graphics

In Swing GUI i need to show an image which will indicates the **Liquid level of the tank** on the basis of **dynamic data**.It would be like a tank image which will show the liquid which is having.How can i draw liquid level?

### Solution:

[Reffer this block-"STEEL SERIES"](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/)

Comment: *"How can i do this in swing.."*  Which part?  Load an image? Display it in a panel or label? Draw the fluid level? Doing it dynamically? *"..with Netbeans IDE?"* The same way you'd do it in Eclipse or an app. written in a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How steampunky are you feeling? Here's a [gauge level](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6Rj6XOY6y4)

Answer (score 2):

Also consider [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), which includes [`DialPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/DialPlot.html) and [`ThermometerPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ThermometerPlot.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513). The latter is designed for temperature, but it illustrates liquid levels well.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a progress bar. Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

You can do a setOrientation() method to make it vertical.