# JDBCCategoryDataset - execute multiple queries

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create three charts inside a JFrame using the [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) class.

How can I give three separate queries? I gave three different queries in the dataset object, but the result was to display three similar charts. In addition, it executes the last query for all three. I have seen the way it is done with [`DefaultPieDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DefaultPieDataset.html) given default (static) values, but I want to retrieve data dynamically from database.

I know I can create several `JDBCCategoryDataset` objects? Is there a better way?

```
package barchart;

import Extra.OpenFile;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class Chart {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

           try {
           JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobfinder",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","giannis", "giannis");

           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Charts");
           frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

           String query = "";
           query = OpenFile.getContent("query"); //Gets the query from a file
                                                // cause it's big.It's a custom class.
           dataset.executeQuery(query);
           JFreeChart chart =
           ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Job Statistics", "Posts/Replys", "Quantity",
           dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

           chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
           CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
           plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
           plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

           BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
           renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.CYAN);
           renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.DARK_GRAY);
           renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
           renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);

           ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
           chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 270));

           frame.add(chartPanel);


//               query = "SELECT occuDscr Jobs,COUNT(pstOccuId) Quantity FROM occupation_field " +
//                       "INNER JOIN job_post ON occuId = pstOccuId GROUP BY Jobs";
//               dataset.executeQuery(query);
//               JFreeChart chart1 =
//               ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Job Statistics", "Posts/Replys", "Quantity",
//               dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
//
//               ChartPanel chartPanel1 = new ChartPanel(chart1, false);
//               chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500/2, 270/2));
//
//               frame.add(chartPanel1);
//
//               query = "SELECT occuDscr Jobs,COUNT(usrOccuId) Quantity FROM occupation_field " +
//                       "INNER JOIN users ON occuId = usrOccuId GROUP BY Jobs";
//               dataset.executeQuery(query);
//               JFreeChart chart2 =
//               ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Job Statistics", "Posts/Replys", "Quantity",
//               dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
//
//               ChartPanel chartPanel2 = new ChartPanel(chart2, false);
//               chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500/2, 270/2));
//
//              frame.add(chartPanel2);

           frame.setVisible(true);
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.pack();

           RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(frame);

       } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
             System.out.println("Error Occurred " + fe.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
       } catch (IOException ie) {
             System.out.println("Error Occurred " + ie.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
             System.out.println("Error Occurred " + ce.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
      }  catch (SQLException se) {
             System.out.println("Error Occurred " + se.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the simplest approach is to give each panel it's own query-specific [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html). In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513), each `ThermometerDemo` panel has it's own `DefaultValueDataset`.

Alternatively, define a class having a single `JDBCCategoryDataset` that retrieves all the data required to compose three `CategoryDataset` instances, and expose static factory methods that each return the individual dataset required for each pie chart.

Addendum: The latter approach assumes that there is some useful heuristic to distinguish among subsets of the full result set. As an example, here's a partial implementation for contiguous subsets:

```
/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835974 */
public class MyCategoryDataset implements CategoryDataset{

    private JDBCCategoryDataset set;
    private List subList;

    private MyCategoryDataset(JDBCCategoryDataset set, int first, int last) {
        this.set = set;
        subList = set.getRowKeys().subList(first, first);
    }

    public static CategoryDataset createSubset(
            JDBCCategoryDataset set, int first, int last) {
        return new MyCategoryDataset(set, first, first);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable getRowKey(int row) {
        return (Comparable) subList.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowIndex(Comparable key) {
        return subList.indexOf(key);
    }

    @Override
    public List getRowKeys() {
        return subList;
    }

    // TODO
    //@Override
    //public Comparable getColumnKey(int column) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public int getColumnIndex(Comparable key) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public List getColumnKeys() {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public Number getValue(Comparable rowKey, Comparable columnKey) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public int getRowCount() {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public int getColumnCount() {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public Number getValue(int row, int column) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public void addChangeListener(DatasetChangeListener listener) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public void removeChangeListener(DatasetChangeListener listener) {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public DatasetGroup getGroup() {}
    //
    //@Override
    //public void setGroup(DatasetGroup group) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you help me compose one CategoryDataset instance with some code sample.