# the freechart doesn't create the chart till the whole data is entered

Tags: java, jtable, jfreechart

i created j table i will update this table monthly , i created a free chart to draw a chart using the data from the table , but i doesn't work till the whole column is entered
i used for loop to create the table so it will have data < i where i= the row count of j table

can someone help me ??

```
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int rowcount=Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(rowcount);


    double o=(double) table.getModel().getValueAt(4,2 );
    double p=(double) table.getModel().getValueAt(3,1 );
    double q=(double) table.getModel().getValueAt(4,1 );
    //double  lossunit=abs(p-q);
   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,achievement);
     dtm.setValueAt(100*abs((o-p)/(p-q)), 4,3 );
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int rowcount=Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    DefaultCategoryDataset dts = new DefaultCategoryDataset();


    for(int i=0 ;i<rowcount;i++){
    double q =(double) table.getModel().getValueAt(i,2 );
    dataset .setValue(q,"achieve%", "month"+(i+1) );
    double z =(double) table.getModel().getValueAt(i,1 );
    dts.setValue(z , "achieve%", "month"+(i+1) );
    }
    //XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Result", "month", "achieve%", (CategoryDataset) dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    JFreeChart Chart1 = ChartFactory.createLineChart(" Target", "month", "achieve%",(CategoryDataset) dts, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryPlot n = Chart1.getCategoryPlot();
    p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
    n.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
    ChartFrame frame =new ChartFrame("bar chart", chart);
    ChartFrame frame1 =new ChartFrame("bar chart", Chart1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1200,300);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setSize(1200,300);
    frame1.setLocation(0, 300);


}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i forgot to ask if i can make the both charts on the same graph

Comment: Yes; you can [edit] your question to clarify; also include a [mcve] that focuses on a single problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Displaying data on table into jfreechart*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24454660/230513).