# JfreeCharts specify a particular width for XYBarchart

Tags: java, jfreechart, resize

I am using JfreeCharts to make a XYBarChart and I would like to specify a particular width for the chart. 
From what I understand from the forums this is not possible. 
**Is this truely the case?**

I have tried:

changing the lowerMargin and upperMargin of the horizontal axis.

using `renderer.setMargin()` (`renderer` was accessed using `chart.getPlot().getRenderer`)

However, this has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the container of the chart (the `ChartPanel` if you're using Swing, the `ChartComposite` if you're using SWT, ...)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `setSize()`, you can specify the desired parameters in your [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#ChartPanel%28org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) constructor, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513).