# Jfreechart - any option for multiple XY charts like with the multi pie plot?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there anything similar to the multiPiePlot Chart but for xy plots?  I have an application that needs to print two or three xy plots on one page.  I know you can put multiple data sets on the same plot, but the requirements specify that each must be a separate chart on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the solution trashgod used, but I've extended the solution to support the sort of printing I wanted to be able to do with my application.

I wanted to be able to print like JFreechart usually does, but put multiples of its graphs on each page in a grid and have it stretch and expand to the page nicely.  Using this function, I was able to generate a print that matches the image below:

[image: Sample Print]

Basically I extended JPanel and implemented the Printable interface. to make a panel that will contain all the JFreecharts I may want to display/print. The panel will arrange them in a grid fashion based on some layoutinstructions you provide.

The print function for the panel basically takes a page format like normal, but then sub divides the page into the grid specified before.  It then takes each of these cells and makes a pageformat for each of them.  Then it will tell each JFreeChart ChartPanel to print to each of those PageFormat cells.

## CustomChartPanel:

```
package com.company.jfreeChartCustom;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;

import com.lowagie.text.Row;

/**
 * The CustomChartPanel is used to display/print multiple JFreeCharts
 * Users should only interact with this class with the methods defined
 * below in order to get the proper functionality.  Using
 * inherited methods may produce unwanted display/print behavior if you
 * add components other than JFreeCharts.
 * 
 */
public class CustomChartPanel extends JPanel implements Printable{

    List<JFreeChart> charts = new ArrayList<JFreeChart>();
    List<ChartPanel> panels = new ArrayList<ChartPanel>();
    ChartLayoutInstructions layoutInstructions;

    public CustomChartPanel(){
        super();
    }

    public CustomChartPanel(JFreeChart chart){
        super();
        charts.add(chart);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a CustomChartPanel which displays 1 or more charts in a grid-like fashion
     * described by the layoutInstructions you pass in.  Note that if you pass in more
     * charts than there are columns specified in the ChartLayoutInstructions then excess
     * charts will not be displayed or printed.
     * @param charts
     * @param layoutInstructions
     */
    public CustomChartPanel(List<JFreeChart> charts, ChartLayoutInstructions layoutInstructions){
        super();
        this.layoutInstructions = layoutInstructions;
        for(JFreeChart chart : charts){
            this.charts.add(chart);
        }
        createUIComponents();
    }

    protected void createUIComponents(){
        int size = Math.min(layoutInstructions.getColumns() * layoutInstructions.getRows(), charts.size());
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(layoutInstructions.getRows(), layoutInstructions.getColumns()));


        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
            System.err.println("Adding chart");
            ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(charts.get(i));
            chartPanel.setMaximumDrawHeight(20000);
            chartPanel.setMinimumDrawHeight(0);
            chartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth(20000);
            chartPanel.setMinimumDrawWidth(0);
            chartPanel.setPopupMenu(null);
            panels.add(chartPanel);
            this.add(chartPanel);
        }
    }

    public void createPrintJob(){
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
        PageFormat pf2 = job.pageDialog(pf);
        if (pf2 != pf) {
            job.setPrintable(this, pf2);
            if (job.printDialog()) {
                try {
                    job.print();
                }
                catch (PrinterException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {
        System.err.println("PRINTING");
        //Divide the current page format into sections based
        //on the layout instructions received in the constructor
        //a new pagelayout is created for each cell in the grid
        //that will then be passed along to the print method of
        //each chart panel.  


        if(pageIndex != 0){
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        List<PageFormat> pageFormats = new ArrayList<PageFormat>();

        //setup all the page formats needed for the grid cells.
        double x = pf.getImageableX();
        double y = pf.getImageableY();
        double cellWidth = pf.getImageableWidth() / layoutInstructions.getColumns();
        double cellHeight = pf.getImageableHeight() / layoutInstructions.getRows();

        for(int i=1; i <= layoutInstructions.getRows(); i++){
            double rowOffset = (i-1)*cellHeight + y;
            for(int j=1; j <= layoutInstructions.getColumns(); j++){
                PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
                Paper paper = new Paper();
                double columnOffset = (j-1)*cellWidth + x;
                paper.setImageableArea(columnOffset, rowOffset, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                format.setPaper(paper);
                pageFormats.add(format);
            }
        }

        //have each chartpanel print on the graphics context using its
        //particular PageFormat
        int size = Math.min(pageFormats.size(), panels.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
            panels.get(i).print(g, pageFormats.get(i), pageIndex);

        }

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

## ChartLayoutInstructions:

I have plans to extend this class for my own purposes for defining more advanced behaviors.  that's why I use this class rather than just having rows and columns defined in the constructor of the CustomChartPanel Class.

```
package com.company.jfreeChartCustom;

/**
 * ChartLayoutInstructions are used to specify how charts should be
 * layed out on screen and in print format.  
 *
 */
public class ChartLayoutInstructions {

    int rows;
    int columns;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param rows number of rows in the display/print grid
     * @param columns number of columns in the display/print grid
     */
    public ChartLayoutInstructions(int rows, int columns, boolean allowSwap){
        this.rows = Math.abs(rows);
        this.columns = Math.abs(columns);
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = Math.abs(rows);
    }

    public int getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(int columns) {
        this.columns = Math.abs(columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor with one chart parameter is incomplete. Add;            `code    layoutInstructions = new ChartLayoutInstructions(1, 1, false);
   createUIComponents();    `

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simply add your `ChartPanel` instances to a `JPanel` having `GridLayout(0, 1)` for a top-to-bottom arrangement. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) uses an orthogonal `GridLayout(1, 0)` to set three panels across.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, printing works by rendering what's on screen, although you may want to change the page orientation for a horizontal layout.

Comment: I used your solution for displaying them and then customized things for getting them to print properly. I outlined my solution in another answer.  Thanks for the help.