# Multiple JFreeCharts on a window

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm trying to get multiple jfreecharts displaying within a single window.  Apparently this is not possible with the included ChartFrame so I attempted to add multiple copies of the same chart to a JFrame which didn't work.  Any ideas?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chart");
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart1));
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart2));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

With this code, I only get one chart in the JFrame.

EDIT:
I added another data set and chart but it still only displays one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cause of your problem is layout of `frame.getContentPane()`.
Default layout at the `JFrame` content pane - `BorderLayout`. Read more about `BorderLayout` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).
This operation

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart));
```

equals

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and add `ChartPanel` to the CENTER area of the content pane. Second `ChartPanel` you add to CENTER area too. Then you add two component to the same area the last added one hides all previous added. Thus second ChartPanel hides first one.

You need change layout for `frame.getContentPane()`.

You may use the same chart to two `ChartPanel`.
Try to change you code to

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chart");
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

It is not code for production. It just example to show two `ChartPanel` on the frame.

Comment: +1 for considering the layout; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) using `GridLayout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a suspicion it was some sort of layout issue but this shows how little I use swing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have different chart instances. If you use the same reference, the last one that is added to a ChartPanel will be displayed.

Comment: I added another chart instance (edit above) and it still only displays one.