# Java Swing - How to speed up program

Tags: java, performance, swing, plot, jfreechart

I wrote the program on the basis of JFreeChart library. Possibility of change of points of the diagram, creation of new diagrams online, scaling, etc are realized in my program. A problem that the program works slowly if there more than 30 plots. How it is possible to speed up the program?

I can show a code, but I don't know, whether there is a sense. Also I don't know, on what part of a code leaves most of all computer resources. How can I find this parts of code? I work in NetBeans.

Comment: Netbeans comes with a profiler, perhaps you should try seeing where most of the time is spent in your code...

Comment: *"How it is possible to speed up the program?"*  Even if it is not possible to speed up the app., you can trick the user into thinking it takes less time by providing a `JProgressBar`..

Comment: You can try tinkering with `useBuffer`; this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) is faster without the buffer.