# Java Swing - JFreeChart works slowly

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I use JFreeChart to plot splines and polynimials.
For charts I use `XYSeriesCollection`. When I have more than 30 splines, my program works slowly. **YourKit** shows me this:[image]

As far as I understand, the draw of splines works slowly. How it is possible to get rid of this problem? Movement of a point lags behind a mouse already in case of 30 splines, so what will be in case of 100+ splines?

Comment: Any help from the suggestion in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26876749/230513)? Do you _have_ to display _all_ the charts at once? Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @trashgod thanks, I will delete this question and create new complete! Unfortunately, 'useBuffer' don't work for me :(