# jfreechart general issue on the possibility of interactlively modify a displayed curve dragging mouse

Tags: java, dynamic, mouseevent, jfreechart

I've never used JFreeChart before. It has been told me that it's a pretty good product for drawing charts in Java.

I have a doubt, and I would like to have some advices by someone that  has already some JFreeChart experience:

is JFreeChart designed only for display static precomputed set of values?

Or is there any "pretty easy" way to handle mouse event (possibly dragging) in order to dynamically change the displayed curves (and consequentely the associated data set)?

With "pretty easy" I mean been able to do the following without having to write too much lines of code:

1. Click on a displayed chart (for example Line Chart ) and identify the closer point of the dataset displayed .
2. Use some sort of drag event to change the dataset value according to the movement of the mouse
3. Show the updated chart interactively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can certainly handle dynamic charts, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series); and you can interact in a variety of ways with an existing chart, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible).

Addendum: Here's a few more specifics:

1. The default tooltip generator displays data when you hover over a point, but you can also supply a custom generator.
2. `ChartPanel` implements both `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`.
3. The [JWS demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) is a trove of examples, many interactive. The `crosshair` demos are particularly appealing.

Comment: @trashgod To be honest I don't see in the demo application even one example in which you can modify values by drag&drop.

Comment: DnD is outside the scope of [tag:jfreechart], but `ChartPanel` is a `JComponent` for which you can write a `TransferHandler`.