# Closing jfreechart swing window closing down the whole application

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have integrated [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChart3DDemo3withitemlabelsdisplayed.htm) Jfreechart Bar Demo with my swing application.
I have put the following code in the action performed method of a button, this code was previously in the main method of the Bar Demo class.

```
final BarChart3DDemo3 demo = new BarChart3DDemo3("3D Bar Chart Demo 3");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
```

This is generating the Bar Chart. But on closing the Bar chart Window. My Whole application is getting closed.

I have tried to insert `demo.getDefaultCloseOperation(ApplicationFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` 
but its not working. Although not giving any error.

I have also tried to insert this in the BarChart3DDemo3 constructor but its giving error getDefaultCloseOperation() method does not take int argument.

I have no clue what to do next? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Also no luck with HIDE_ON_CLOSE..

Comment: You mean *set*DefaultCloseOperation(...DISPOSE...), right?

Comment: DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and HIDE_ON_CLOSE both are working fine with JFrame which was non responsive for ApplicationFrame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that [`ApplicationFrame`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/ApplicationFrame.html) "listens for window closing events, and responds by shutting down the JVM." It's intended for demo applications. Instead, put your `ChartPanel` in a `JFrame`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575).

Comment: I have removed ApplicationFrame and replaced with JFrame and its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

> public class LineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame ,
>
> public class LineChart_AWT extends **JFrame** is working fine.