# Add a jfree bar chart into a scroll pane

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, bar-chart

I have a JFree Bar Chart. the dataset is populated using DefaultCategoryDataset ,
There may be situations when the values on both the domain and range axis are such that these values are not very clearly visible.

I need something like a scrollPane into which the chart can be added. But it looks like the ChartPanel cannot be added into a JScrollPane

Is there any way of doing this ?

Thanks Bhavya

Comment: Why aren't they clearly visible?

Comment: the number of categories in the domain axis is very high as a result of which they are not visible clearly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setLowerMargin()` and/or `getUpperMargin()` on the relevant [`CategoryAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html) to improve the appearance. Alternatively, you can use a [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html) in conjunction with a `JSlider`.

Addendum: A third alternative is to use zooming, which is enabled by default, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible).

Comment: @trashgod for total lazyness by OP to read official tutorial +1

Comment: @trashgod , i would like to make some more changes so that the graph looks better many be I can attach the graph and how it looks like for your suggestions . how do i attach a file here ?

Comment: @mkorbel where is this official tutorial is this the JFreeChart documentation ?

Comment: @mKorbel: I can recommend the free [examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-frame.html)(click class name for source) and the modestly priced [JFreeChart Developer Guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html). @Bhavya: You can edit your question to include code or links. Disclaimer: not affiliated with Object Refinery.