# jfreechart change the entries on the range scale to reflect Logarithmic values

Tags: java, logging, jfreechart

In the bar chart that I am trying to display I see that because some range values are really high some of the lower value bars are not visible at all.

Is there any way in which I can modify the range axis so that all the bars are visible ?

I am wondering is using a LogarithmicAxis here will be helpful.

Thanks,
Bhavya

Comment: Have you tried zooming, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448724/add-a-jfree-bar-chart-into-a-scroll-pane/6448792#6448792).

Comment: @trashgod I used the LogAxis and it seemed to have worked

Comment: Excellent. If you have a simple example, I would encourage you to post it as an answer.