# Combined XY realtime plots

Tags: charts, real-time, jfreechart

Ok so there was confusion on what i was asking. I need help adjusting the algorithm I already have here. First part I need the X axis to be time and Y axis to be data read from file the user specifies the directory. This data file will be written every second so the graph should pause or graph 0 if there is no data and time is still running. The purpose of this program is that a script in linux will write to a file cpu, memory and power consumption and I have to graph that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple `TimeSeries` to a `TimeSeriesCollection`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible).

Comment: I don't see a clear need for a combined plot; perhaps you can amplify.

Comment: how do i make that real time? and change the X to be time and Y to be whats read from file?

Comment: It would depend on the file's format. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863), which uses `Second`.

Comment: if I wanted to have 3 graphs like that where would i have to put a loop or is it something more simple? The file would be a .txt file that can be read as data is written.

Comment: Start by solving the problem for one, short sample series, then refine the code; edit your question to include your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).