# Auto-Scale Y-Axis in JfreeChart

Tags: java, scale, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

I am using `JFreeChart` to create candlestick charts in my Java app. However, my charts end up looking like this:

[image: capturebhx]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/capturebhx.png/

I would like to have the Y-axis automatically scaled so that the chart looks more like this:

[image: capture2wl]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/capture2wl.png/

I think `org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis.configure()` will do this, but I'm not sure. I can't seem to find a way to tie my `JFreeChart`object, or `ChartPanel` object to this `NumberAxis` object. Please help me, I am lost and have been looking for a long time to try and tie these objects together. Or, if you can find another way, that'd be great too!

Some code:

```
...
private DefaultHighLowDataset dataset;
private JFreeChart chart;
private ChartPanel chart_panel;

...

// creates dataset, then chart from dataset, then chart_panel from chart
dataset = new DefaultHighLowDataset("", date, high, low, open, close, volume);
chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart("Blank", "Time", "Price", dataset, false);
chart_panel = new ChartPanel(chart); // what you see in the images
...
```

Comment: Some code snippets could help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure to [`setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setAutoRangeIncludesZero%28boolean%29) or "the axis range…is forced to include zero."

Addendum:

> I still don't know how to link a `NumberAxis` object to a `ChartPanel` object or `JFreeChart` object.

You may want to look into the examples in [`org.jfree.chart.demo`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-summary.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible). If this is *terra incognita*, I'd recommend [*The JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Comment: That might do it too, but I still don't know how to link a NumberAxis object to a ChartPanel object or JFreeChart object.

Comment: I've elaborated above. If you're still having trouble, post the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) used to create your [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/capturebhx.png/).

Comment: me too have the same problem but i am using afreechart library for android. and this code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @arjunkn: See [ask] a new question, and tag it [tag:android].

Comment: How would I get a NumberAxis instance if I created a plot using the ChartFactory? So far I've been using the unsafe type cast  ((NumberAxis)myChart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis()).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false)   which is a somewhat dirty hack. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Joerg: Construct your own axis, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38080778/230513).

Answer (score 6):

I did it like this:

```
     final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(
            "Candlestick Demo", "Time", "Price", dataset, false);

    double lowestLow = getLowestLow(dataset);
    double highestHigh = getHighestHigh(dataset);

    chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setRange(lowestLow*0.95, highestHigh*1.05);
```

I calculate the lowest low and lowest high using these functions

```
private double getLowestLow(DefaultHighLowDataset dataset){
    double lowest;
    lowest = dataset.getLowValue(0,0);
    for(int i=1;i<dataset.getItemCount(0);i++){
        if(dataset.getLowValue(0,i) < lowest){
            lowest = dataset.getLowValue(0,i);
        }
    }

    return lowest;
}


private double getHighestHigh(DefaultHighLowDataset dataset){
    double highest;
    highest = dataset.getHighValue(0,0);
    for(int i=1;i<dataset.getItemCount(0);i++){
        if(dataset.getLowValue(0,i) > highest){
            highest = dataset.getHighValue(0,i);
        }
    }

    return highest;
}
```

This seems to give me a very nice candlestick chart that makes good use of the Y-axis range. Hope this helps.