# Disable date-formatting for domain axis in JFreeChart when x-data is Long

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using an `XYPlot` (`ChartFactory.createXYStepChart`) and the problem is the X-Axis is sample frames whose type is `long`, so I'm populating my `XYSeries` by calling `xyseries.add(long, double)`. The result is that JFreeChart automatically interprets the x-values as `Date` instances, rendering them as something that looks like SMPTE time code:

[image]

Instead I want to show the X values as plain (integer number) sample frames. How can I tell the plot or the renderer to revert to default numeric formatting, leaving the `long`s as `long`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ChartFactory.createXYStepChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYStepChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-) creates a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) for the `xAxis`, as seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.2021). `DateAxis` interprets your `long` values as milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time); it displays them as dates. You can either

- Create a new `NumberAxis` and use it in a call to the plot's `setDomainAxis()` method.
- Create your own factory method that instantiates `NumberAxis` directly; a related example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080778/230513).