# How to change from line chart to bar chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I have this line chart and want to make it a bar chart, but I'm new to Java and am not knowing if it possible since the x-axis is `TimeSeries`. This is the code I have that visualizes the line chart:

```
public class Time {

private static Time INSTANCE;
public static boolean isInitialized = false;

private Marker marker;
private Long markerStart;
private Long markerEnd;

private XYPlot plot;

long last_lowerBound;
long last_upperBound;

@Inject
public Time() {

}

Composite comp;
TimeSeriesCollection dataset;
ChartPanel panel;
JFreeChart chart;
protected Point endPoint;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
    comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.EMBEDDED);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(comp);

    JApplet rootContainer = new JApplet();

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Timeline");
    dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();

    String plotTitle = "";
    String xaxis = "Time";
    String yaxis = "Docs";
    PlotOrientation orientation = PlotOrientation.VERTICAL;
    boolean show = false;
    boolean toolTips = true;
    boolean urls = false;

    chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(plotTitle, xaxis, yaxis, dataset, show, toolTips, urls );

    // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
    plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.gray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.gray);
    plot.setOutlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.getRangeAxis().setLabel("");
    plot.getDomainAxis().setLabel("");
    ValueAxis y_axis = plot.getRangeAxis();     // Y
    ValueAxis x_axis = plot.getDomainAxis();    // X
    Font font = new Font("Veranda", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    y_axis.setTickLabelFont(font);
    x_axis.setTickLabelFont(font);
    x_axis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.black);
    y_axis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.black);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setAxisLineVisible(false);

    final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    // renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Should I only update this line: `chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(plotTitle, xaxis, yaxis, dataset, show, toolTips, urls );` or I should change it completely?

I tried changing this part like this but it doesn't show anything:

```
dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();

    String plotTitle = "";
    String xaxis = "Time";
    String yaxis = "Docs";
    PlotOrientation orientation = PlotOrientation.VERTICAL;
    boolean show = false;
    boolean toolTips = true;
    boolean urls = false;

    chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(plotTitle, xaxis, yaxis, (CategoryDataset) dataset, orientation, show, toolTips, urls);


    chart.setBackgroundPaint(null);
    chart.setBackgroundImageAlpha(0.0f);

    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
    plot.setRangeZeroBaselineVisible(false);
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(COLOR_INVISIBLE);
    plot.setBackgroundImageAlpha(0.0f);

    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, AttributeGuiTools.getColorForValueType(Ontology.NOMINAL));
    renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
    renderer.setShadowVisible(false); } }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a suitable [`XYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html), such as [`IntervalXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/IntervalXYDataset.html), you can replace [`ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-) with [`ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYBarChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset-), which provides for an optional `DateAxis`. The example below uses the same dataset to create both charts.

```
IntervalXYDataset dataset = createDataset();
f.add(createPanel(ChartFactory.createXYBarChart("Data", "Time", true, "Value", dataset)));
f.add(createPanel(ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Data", "Time", "Value", dataset)));
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickMarkPosition;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnitType;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Year;
import org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362133/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612723/230513
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Data");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        IntervalXYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        f.add(createPanel(ChartFactory.createXYBarChart("Data", "Time", true, "Value", dataset)));
        f.add(createPanel(ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Data", "Time", "Value", dataset)));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ChartPanel createPanel(JFreeChart chart) {
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        final DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.YEAR, 1));
        domainAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);
        domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"));
        return new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 250);
            }
        };
    }

    private IntervalXYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Value");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            series.add(new Year(c.getTime()), i + 1);
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        }
        return new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499848/230513) that compares using a factory vs. constructing manually.

Comment: @tashgod thanks a lot, I tried to implement this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076305/jfreechart-barchart-no-gradient/7092567#7092567 of yours for the `standardbarpainter` but it doesn't work since I'm using `XYBarRenderer`

Comment: @ga4696: Glad it helped; for a matte look, use a `StandardXYBarPainter`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20StandardXYBarPainter), or write a suitable factory method.