# How to hide points in XY Step Area Chart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

How can  I hide the points in an [XY Step Area Chart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYStepAreaChartDemo.htm). The points are highlighted in the picture.

[image: StepAreaChart pointers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the possible approaches:

- Ask the [`XYStepAreaRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYStepAreaRenderer.html) to make the shapes invisible:

  ```
  // shapes      
  final XYStepAreaRenderer r = (XYStepAreaRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
  r.setShapesVisible(false);
  ```
- Specify [`XYStepAreaRenderer.AREA`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYStepAreaRenderer.html#AREA) (area only) for the `type` in a custom factory method, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499848/230513) for a related renderer.

  ```
  XYItemRenderer r = new XYStepAreaRenderer(XYStepAreaRenderer.AREA,…);
  ```

Shapes *not* visible:
[image: after]

Shapes visible:
[image: before]

Comment: Great. I have tested and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.