# How to update a chart in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a combinedXYPlot and a drop-down list. I want to update my chart based on user input from drop-down. How to do this?
I tried the following code

```
frmJPanel.getContentPane().removeAll();

frmJPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

initChart(option);

frmJPanel.repaint();
```

The changes are reflected only after I minimize/ maximize the window. What is the function that needs to be called? What is the better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) "registers with the chart to receive notification of changes to any component of the chart. The chart is redrawn automatically whenever this notification is received." There are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series).

Comment: I had to include the function call - frmPanel.validate() for the changes to be updated.

Comment: I'm surprised. Is `frmPanel` a `JPanel` or a `ChartPanel`? Cf. this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart/7073428#7073428), which inadvertently confounds the two.

Comment: its a JPanel. It should have been frmJPanel.validate()

Answer (score 1):

I have my chart inside a org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel. When I want to update the chart I simply call on the chartPanel.repaint() method.

The chartPanel itself is added another JPanel, which in turn is placed in the main layout of the application.

Comment: I'm surprised that `repaint()` is required, although I can't see any harm.