# How to rotate group labels when using a GroupedStackedBarRenderer in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a followed the demo from JFreeChart ([StackedBarChartDemo5](http://read.pudn.com/downloads92/sourcecode/graph/359672/JFreeChart/src/com/rjsoft/barcharts/categoryplot/StackedBarChartDemo5.java__.htm)) in order to create a plot allowing me to use the `GroupedStackedBarRenderer`.

Basically, I'm plotting air times for each station (represents a stack in a bar), connected to a radio (represents a bar in the plot), for both receive and transmit (RX and TX). 
The plot looks something like this :
[image]

There are two categories (RX and TX) and several groups (radios). As you can see, currently, the radio MACs are unreadable.
I would like to rotate these labels, in order to make the plot legible.  
I have used the following piece of code in order to try and rotate the labels: `subCategoryAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 4));`
This only rotated the labels of the categories (RX and TX) instead of the labels of the groups (radio MACs): 
[image]

I have also tried several other approaches, all of which lead to nowhere... How do I rotate these sublabels?

Here is the underlying code that I used to populate the labels with :

```
SubCategoryAxis subCategoryAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Radio MACs (separate Rx and Tx plots)");
subCategoryAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05D);  

    // subCategoryAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 4));

    KeyToGroupMap keyToGroupMap = null;
    final Set<String> radios = Sets.newHashSet();
    for (Entry<XRadio, Triplet<XStation, Double, Double>> entryMap: channelTimes.entries()) {
        final String radioMac = entryMap.getKey().getMac();
        if (keyToGroupMap == null)
            keyToGroupMap = new KeyToGroupMap(radioMac);

        if (!radios.contains(radioMac)) {
            subCategoryAxis.addSubCategory(radioMac);
            radios.add(radioMac);
        }

        final Triplet<XStation, Double, Double> chTriplet = entryMap.getValue();                           
        final String seriesKey = radioMac + ":" + chTriplet.a.getMac();
        keyToGroupMap.mapKeyToGroup(seriesKey, radioMac);                                
        model.getDataset().addValue(chTriplet.b, seriesKey, "Rx");
        model.getDataset().addValue(chTriplet.c, seriesKey, "Tx");
    }

    if (keyToGroupMap == null)
        return;

    groupedStackedBarRenderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(keyToGroupMap);                
    groupedStackedBarRenderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());      
    groupedStackedBarRenderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);                    
    groupedStackedBarRenderer.setItemMargin(0.1D); // 10 %
    groupedStackedBarRenderer.getPlot().setDomainAxis(subCategoryAxis);
```

Comment: You may be able to use one of the approaches shown in [How do I rotate tick mark labels on the domain of a number axis in JFreeChart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart).

Answer (score -1):

<s>You can set the rotation on the `CategoryAxis` in radians:</s>

<s>`subCategoryAxis.setLabelAngle(-Math.PI / 2);`</s>

EDIT:
It seems the `SubCategoryAxis` ignores rotation for sub-lables.

In the `SubCategoryAxis#drawSubCategoryLabels` method there is a call to `TextUtilities.drawRotatedString()` with `angle=0`.

Note: The examples are from 1.13.

The correct solution would be to make a patch that fixes the issue and submit said patch to the developers.

As for fixing it for your case, you could extend the `SubCategoryAxis` and call the `TextUtilities.drawRotatedString()` with the correct angle.

Comment: I have already tried this, but all this does is rotates the label for the description of the axis (it rotates "Radio MACs (separate RX and TX plots)"