# Rotate label in DateAxis of JFreeChart

Tags: java, date, jfreechart

I have a chart done with JfreeChart using TimeSeries.
In the range axis I have values and in the Domain Axis I have dates (DateAxis).
Those Dates I can display them in horizontal or vertical depending the selection of dateAxis.setVerticalTickLabels, true for vertical, and false for horizontal.

My question is: Is possible to display de dates of DateAxis with an angle like the method of CategoryAxis setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);?

I found a method called setLabelAngle that i can use in DateAxis, but no matter what value i put inside, the labels are not rotated.

Any suggestion?

Kind regards,

Comment: Try `DateDomainAxis` cited in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart#comment49979885_7071057) seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart).