# Error with a class customiser for charts

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I want to customise my charts so I want to use a class customiser,
I have used the following code  to change the categorie label to vertical , but I don't know why it generate an error!

the code:

```
 public void customize(JFreeChart jfc, JRChart jrc) {
  CategoryPlot myPlot = jfc.getCategoryPlot();
  HorizontalCategoryAxis axis = (HorizontalCategoryAxis)myPlot.getDomainAxis();
  axis.setVerticalCategoryLabels(true);
 }
```

the error is:

```
 cannot find symbol : Class HorizontalCategoryAxis
```

Also I have tried:

```
    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = (CategoryItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new   StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", new DecimalFormat("0.00"));
    renderer.setLabelGenerator(generator);
    renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true);
    XYItemRenderer renderer2 = (XYItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    XYItemLabelGenerator generator2 = new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{2}", new  DecimalFormat("0.00"));
    renderer.setLabelGenerator(generator);
```

and the errors:

**cannot find symbol** appear for the line :

```
renderer.setLabelGenerator(generator);
```

and

**no suitable constructor** for

```
XYItemLabelGenerator generator2
```

my reference is:

http://files.blogjava.net/hao446tian/jfreechart-1.0.1-US_developer_guide.pdf

**UPDATE**
Still I can't see the categorieExpression( on the Y axis)  :(((

[image]

Comment: The error is, it would seem, that `HorizontalCategoryAxis` is not in your class path. Ensure you have all the appropriate jars in your classpath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the steps to use Cutomiser Chart Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173261/what-are-the-steps-to-use-cutomiser-chart-class)

Comment: @Jes ,I have add JfreChart.jar to my project, should I add somthing else?

Comment: I believe the `HorizontalCategoryAxis` has been deprecateded, or at some point removed. What version of JFreeChart are you running? Your developer manual suggests you should be running 1.0.1. Check my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your failed code seems to be version mismatch between your examples and the library you use. The `setLabelGenerator` method has been removed and replaced with `setBaseItemLabelGenerator`:

```
CategoryPlot plot = yourPlot;
CategoryItemRenderer renderer = (CategoryItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new   StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", new DecimalFormat("0.00"));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
XYItemRenderer renderer2 = (XYItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
XYItemLabelGenerator generator2 = new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{2}", 
        new  DecimalFormat("0.00"),
        new  DecimalFormat("0.00"));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
```

You can see in my example that the `StandardXYItemLabelGenerator` takes two formats, one for the x values and one for y.

As for the use of `HorizontalCategoryAxis` it suffered the same fate as `setLabelGenerator`. Assuming you want a vertical plot with a `CategoryAxis` that has labels that are vertical, not horizontal, you can use `setLabelAngle` to achieve the desired effect:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart jfc, JRChart jrc) {
    CategoryPlot myPlot = jfc.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryAxis axis = myPlot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setLabelAngle(-Math.PI / 2);
}
```

Comment: ,I have tried your answer ,the error disappeared and a report was generated ,I will update my post with the report it still a mess!

Comment: It seems the label angle is not being set. Are you certain the category axis is not set elsewhere? Try setting a breakpoint in the body of `setLabelAngle`.

Comment: hello, yes you are right :) ,final question could In use the same class custoiser for a barChart 3D ?

Comment: The code so far is generic for the `BarRenderer` and `CategoryPlot` respectively. `BarRenderer3D` extends `BarRenderer` so you should be able to just switch the renderer out.

Comment: +1 for elucidating the evolving API, which is instructive in itself.