# How to call print option of JFreeChart

Tags: java, printing, jfreechart

I have an application with some JFreeCharts. When I right-click them, one of the default options is "Print", so I can print the chart in paper.

I want to replicate that option in my application main menu, File/Print, but I don't know what function of the chart does this, and when I try to look for this information in the JFreeChart Developer Guide, I get hundreds of System.PRINTln when searching.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that would be the [`createChartPrintJob()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#createChartPrintJob%28%29) method within [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html). (Or perhaps the [`print()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#print%28java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.print.PageFormat,%20int%29) method, depending on what you want to do.)

Details are [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html).

Comment: +1 Conveniently, `ChartPanel ` implements `Printable`. It also hosts other context menu functions, some of which are shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible).

Comment: +1 The createChartPrintJob() is exactly what's its print action does.

Comment: What about including the chart in an already-existing `PrintJob`?