# displaying labels on jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I using a time series chart having 3 years of data. The problem is that I am not able to display the starting date as a label on the Date Axis (x axis)

For example: If I want to display data from 27th Oct, 2008 to 27th Oct, 2011, the label on the Date Axis does not start from 27th Oct, 2008, but starts from a later date.

I would like suggestions as to how to set the label to the starting date.

Any help will be appreciated.

|
 |
 +----------+------------------+-
           Jan 09               April 09

I want "Oct 08" to be displayed at the intersection of x and y axis.

Comment: Did you disable auto-ranging? Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: No I did NOT disable auto-ranging.

Answer (score 2):

As this appears to be a `DateAxis`, a subclass of `ValueAxis`, [`setLowerMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerMargin%28double%29) is available. It should let you see the lower bound; you probably *don't* want it to be clipped at the intersection. You might also experiment with vertical dates, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible/5522583#5522583).