# Getting Renderer for Existing Chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I added a feature to allow users to toggle item labels on charts.  This is implemented by saving a pointer to the XYItemRenderer and calling the renderer's setBaseItemLabelsVisible method to show/hide item labels. However, it would be nicer if I could get a pointer to the XYItemRenderer from the chart instance, but give the cart I only seem to get as far as the plot.  Does anyone know how to get a pointer to the renderer given the chart?

Comment: See [How can I update a JFreeChart's appearance after it's been made visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast the plot to say `CategoryPlot, XYPlot` etc. to get the renderers.

Comment: Thanks! I should have seen that.