# restoring manual domain axis range after zooming out in jfreechart

Tags: java, dns, range, jfreechart, zooming

I'm using JFreeChart to create a timeseries chart in my application.
I'm setting it's domain axis range manually using:

```
    ...
    plot.getDomainAxis().setAutoRange(false);
    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(c1.getTimeInMillis(),c2.getTimeInMillis());
    ...
```

Zooming in to chart and then zooming out (Using mouse on chartplot itself) triggers `AutoRange` on both axis that makes Domain axis range change to series borders and not my own manual rages.

Example (Look at Domain axis's range):
Before zooming in-out (Correct):
[image]

After zooming in-out (Incorrect-is Auto ranged):
[image]

How can I make it to zoom out to my manually set range?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: hi, it edited it and tried to make it SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`restoreAutoBounds()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#restoreAutoBounds%28%29), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), followed by your custom domain setting.

Addendum: The behavior you see is defined in the mouse listener implementation of [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html). You could override `chartProgress()` and restore your domain axis when the chart is finished drawing and not zoomed.

Comment: But this does `AutoRange` while need custom range!

Comment: I've tried to elaborate above, but you still haven't included your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

here a solution:

```
class MyNumberAxis extends org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis
{
    private boolean m_RestoreDefaultAutoRange;

    MyNumberAxis()
    {
        super();
    }

    MyNumberAxis(String label)
    {
        super(label);
    }

    MyNumberAxis(String label, boolean restoreDefaulAutoRange)
    {
        super(label);
        m_RestoreDefaultAutoRange = restoreDefaulAutoRange;
    }

    @Override
    protected void autoAdjustRange()
    {
        if( m_RestoreDefaultAutoRange )
        {
            Plot plot = getPlot();
            if( plot != null && plot instanceof ValueAxisPlot)
            {
                Range r = getDefaultAutoRange();
                setRange(r, false, false);
            }
        }
        else
            super.autoAdjustRange();
    }
}
```

Create an instance of MyNumberAxis setting the boolean to true and use it in your plot (plot.setRangeAxis() method). If you want to behave like the default NumberAxis, pass false as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Magallo's solution above worked great.  I found it even more useful if I added another constructor:

```
MyNumberAxis(String label, boolean restoreDefaulAutoRange, Range defaultRange) {
  super(label);
  m_RestoreDefaultAutoRange = restoreDefaulAutoRange;
  setDefaultAutoRange(defaultRange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom NumberAxis with a fixed range.  Zooming out will auto-zoom to this fixed range.

```
class FixedRangeNumberAxis extends NumberAxis
{
    private Range range;

    FixedRangeNumberAxis(String label, Range range)
    {
        super(label);
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    protected void autoAdjustRange()
    {
        setRange(range, false, false);
    }
}
```