# JFreeChart Maximum Zoom Out

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, zooming

I am working with JFreeChart to create a line graph via an XYPlot which is embedded into an application. The graph is contained within a ChartPanel and added to the background panel of my GUI.

My issue is that the XYPlot appears so zoomed in that I am unable to see any of the lines; simply the whitespace background each side of them!

Is there a way to view the component at its "maximum zoomed out" state so that the graph is understandable?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setZoomInFactor()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setZoomInFactor%28double%29) method works well for this, but you'll have to define *maximum* to choose the factor. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) shows how to add a control that manipulates the zoom state.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should try to use

`getChartPanel().zoomInRange(1, 2);
getChartPanel().restoreAutoBounds()`

Sometimes, only zoomOut just didn't worked for me, so I added zoomIn first and all worked well