# Jfreechart graph get too small after zooming out

Tags: set, jfreechart, mousewheel, linegraph, chartpanel

I have a Jfreechart timeseries line graph running well.

After I add

```
frame.getChartPanel().setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
frame.getChartPanel().setMouseZoomable(true, false);
```

to the code, it can zoom in and out by the mouse wheel, but the problem is when I zoom out, it doesn't have a limit and many blank spaces get into the graph and the line gets smaller and smaller.

Is there a way to set a boundary for the graph so when I zoom out it could only get back to the same size as it generates?

Additional information: the solution in this post [JFreeChart Maximum Zoom Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931852/jfreechart-maximum-zoom-out?rq=1) doesn't work in my case

[[Grahp]The size after it generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf18s.png)

[[Graph]The zoom outed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzOvJ.png)

Comment: If `restoreAutoBounds()` isn't sufficient, you'll probably need a custom `MouseWheelHandler` in `ChartPanel`.

Comment: @trashgod is there an example of how to customing it? I can't find mouseWheelHandler method

Comment: The class `org.jfree.chart.MouseWheelHandler` is included in the distribution.