# JFreeChart: Is there a way to draw long tick labels in two lines in XYPlot

Tags: label, jfreechart

I've got legacy code sample which uses JFreeChart and XYPlot. Now i'm making i18n for that code and most of non-english strings are much longer then english ones. I googled for a way to  wrap strings. No success. Help please!

Comment: maybe i chose wrong word...I don't want to rotate labels. I want labels to be drawed in two or three lines each. Labels are too long to be drawed in one line.

Comment: I should have said: Because multiple lines are [not supported](http://jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4558), you might try `setVerticalTickLabels()`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).

Comment: Sorry, but i'm talking about labels along vertical axis. I should have been more specific. As i see it, only multiple lines will solve my problem. If they are not supported, i'll search for another ways, like ask interpreteurs to shorten translated texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple lines are [not supported](http://jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4558). The `setVerticalTickLabels()` method may be applied to either a domain or a range axis. Because space is limited, interpreters should be frugal. Providing a user setting, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), may mitigate the limitation.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `setMaximumCategoryLabelLines` method from `CategoryAxis`, e.g:

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(3);
```