# overlap in String X-Axis in jfreeChart

Tags: java, string, jfreechart, overlapping

I use jfreechart to  draw chart. type of X-axis in chart is string type.When the number of data grows occurs overlapping in x-axis label. my question is how can i control overlapping in String type x-axis. for integer or dateTime type there are solution and methods but for string  i have found nothing for string type x-axis. If there is a way please help me.thank you

Answer (score 3):

One simple way might be to turn your X-axis labels vertical instead of horizontal. I've used this to prevent overlapping in the labels before.

```
domain.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setVerticalTickLabels(true)` on your domain axis, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).

Comment: thank you for your response, I used this method but when data's is to much how can show some of label in X-axis for not happening overlap. I want to know how it is possible for string type x-axis.

Comment: I'd format the label to fit and put the full string in a tooltip.