# JFreechart X axis data overlap

Tags: jfreechart

I am using jfreechart but the problem is that x axis values get overlap.Is there any way to get rid of it?Here is the output of my chart

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I've just tried using a ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart and it is automatically ommiting some valves.  Take a look at [TimeSeriesDemo1](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) for an example

Comment: We cannot help you fix your code unless you show us your code...

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753961) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913201) are similar to yours and may be helpful.