# About Y-axis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

[image]

The left three lines of data: 0.9,2450,0.4867 in the Y-axis is shown in proportion.
Right three lines (the other two data is too small to show up), how to do the left?

Answer (score 1):

I see several alternatives:

- Condition your data to show relative change, as is done in the chart on the left.
- Add a second axis to show the larger dynamic range, as is done in [`DualAxisDemo2`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).
- Enable the zoom feature in `ChartPanel`, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).