# How can I get my JFree chart to update once its displayed with new Y ranges?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Here is a snipit of how I display my graph, and attempt to re render with the new Y ranges.

```
fpe2.FPE_ExportData(outPutFilePath, xmlOutDescriptorPath);

g = new GraphUtil();
g.collectData(fpe2.subTaskType, "FPE", MaxY, MinY, PlotGraphPanel);
g.graphMake();

PlotGraphPanel.add(g.cPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
PlotGraphPanel.validate();
PlotGraphPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), it's not clear how your program fails. You should only need `validate()` and `repaint()` if you add or remove components. You can update your chart dynamically as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513).