# How to Overlay fitted distribution and histogram using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jframe, distribution, jfreechart

I am using the SSJ Library (which makes use of JFreeChart for drawing graphs) to fit distributions to data (Weibull, Gamma, etc ...) using maximum likelihood estimates. After fitting the distributions, I would like to graph the histogram together with the fitted density curve. I know how to get a histogram using HistogramChart and I know how to get a graph of the fitted density using ContinuousDistChart. The problem is, how do I overlay the two on a single plot?  The HistogramChart class has methods to access the underlying JFreeChart; however, the ContinuousDistChart does not. Is it possible to do this with JFreeChart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `JFrame` returned by methods in `umontreal.iro.lecuyer.charts.ContinuousDistChart` is actually an `org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame`, you can cast and use `getChartPanel()` to drill down. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).