# Dynamic JFreechart

Tags: dynamic, charts, jfreechart

I have a project where I read values from a file. I'd like to create a Dynamic chart where the user will have the ability to choose sections of the graphs and these sections will zoom - in in order to see the results. This functionality is similar to what the Excel does.

For example in the initial graph the user is able to see the graph of the whole year but I'd like to be able to zoom in and to see the graph of a specific day in the same panel,labelm frame.

Is it possible to be done via JFreechart???

Comment: yes. it is possible with JFreeCharts. you can get the values from where the charts are clicked and draw another chart relating to that.

Comment: so if I understood you well, I can design a chart in a frame and then I can get from it specific values which I use to design in a second chart in a different frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Java Web Start demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp), most examples have zooming enabled.  To zoom, right-click to see the context menu, click and drag a selection or use the mouse wheel. [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html#line.70), found in `org.jfree.chart.demo`, is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! The biggest problem that I don't know if it can be solved via JFreechart is that I don't want to import my chart as an image in a frame, but I want to be more dynamic. For example the user should be able to see the frame with the chart (this chart maybe for a whole year) and with his mouse he will be able to zoom-in and to see the chart for a specific day in the same frame

Comment: Try the demo to see how easy it is. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) shows how to add external controls.