# XYPlot without vertical axis and horizontal line grid?

Tags: formatting, jfreechart

Can I draw only vertical data axis (without axis line( in XYPlot and only horizontal line in grid lines (I know the hack - draw them by white color, that is coincident with background color, may be, there is more pure way) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify currency formatting on the range axis using `setNumberFormatOverride()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).

```
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(currency);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

```
  // create a dataset...
  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random Data");
  series.add(1.0, 500.2);
  series.add(10.0, 694.1);

  // Create an XY Line chart
  XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("XY Series Demo",
                                                    null,
                                                    "Y",
                                                    data,
                                                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                                                    true,
                                                    true,
                                                    false);
  XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
  plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
```

The vertical lines are hidden by calling [plot.setDomainGridLinesVisible(false)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setDomainGridlinesVisible%28boolean%29).

Comment: @Eugene: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14443791/230513) to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14442404/230513) was ancillary; don't hesitate to accept this answer if you feel that it addressed your question more directly.