# jfree chart bar chart add $ to range value

Tags: pdf, itext, jfreechart, bar-chart, axis-labels

I implemented a code to represent a bar chart (as of picture). Now my problem is that I want to add $ sign to the values to represent the currencies. So that the values would be:

$0   ----  $500,000  -----  $1,000,000

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), you can use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`:

```
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(currency);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Exactly that's what I found as well

`final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();` 
`NmberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();`
`DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("$##,###,###,###");`
`rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(format);`

Comment: Ah, that's the range axis of a horizontal bar chart.