# Update PieChart in JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have created a PieChart using JFreeChart. I for the life of my cant figure out how to update the chart once it has been created. Is the only way to do that to create an entirely new chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), you can alter a chart after it's been rendered. In this case, update the chart's data *model*, `PieDataset`, and the listening *view* will follow; in these related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20Action), a component's `Action` updates a `Dataset`. In a `MultiplePiePlot`, you can update the appearance of the pie chart *view* directly, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370398/230513).

Addendum: Starting from [`PieChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo2/BarChartDemo1.java), re-factor the dataset and add a suitable `Action`, as shown below.

```
private static final DefaultPieDataset dataset = createDataset();
…
public PieChartDemo1(String title) {
    super(title);
    add(createDemoPanel());
    add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dataset.setValue("Apple", dataset.getValue("Apple").doubleValue() + 1);
        }
    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

[image]