# JFreeChart Bar chart with one category and custom bar positions

Tags: java, pdf, jfreechart

We are already using JFreeChart in our product. But so far for all needed charts it was easy to find description and tutorials.

For new report we need to show `bar chart` with all bars being located not by category but by the value on x-axis. Such as:

```
x-axis: time range between date1 and date2
y-axis: is cost in %currency%
```

So i need to put bars where each bar has specific date where date1 < date < date2 and cost which will define the heigh of bar.

Is there a way to do so in JFreeChart? Or any another free tool? Or any link to proper information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself. Simple solution, so no wonder nobody answered this question. In short: to get empty space instead of bar, the bar value should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You may looking for `ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`, which uses an [`XYBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) illustrates date formatting on the domain axis and currency formatting on the range axis.