# For loop to create multiple series with JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, series

Is there any way to make a lot of new series for JFreeChart by using a for loop? 
I tried something like this. I know that does't work; but if you tell me some other way or maybe fix my code, I would appreciate it.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i=i){

    String series[]=new String[10];
    String dataset[]=new String[10];
                    series[i]="series"+i;
                    dataset[i]="dataset"+i;

    final XYSeries series[i] = new XYSeries("XYGraph");

    XYSeriesCollection dataset[i] = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset[i].addSeries(series[i]);
    chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(i-1,dataset[i]);

    series[i].add(i,2); 
    series[i].add(i,-2);        

     i=i+1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting form this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), I added a `for` loop to create the following variation. The critical issue is identifying the correct parameters to pass to `createSeries()`. This example—having only a `String` and an `int`— is intentionally simple to show the outline.

```
private XYDataset createDataset() {
    TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        tsc.addSeries(createSeries("Series " + String.valueOf(i), i * 100));
    }
    return tsc;
}
```

[image]