# JFreeChart Merged point

Tags: java, jfreechart, trend

I'm using JFreechart to analyze sample data of some devices.
The data i collect is high frequency recorded and when i try to visualize the data the chart seems unreadable cause full of point.

[image]

One solution i think is to merge the nearest point in unzoomed state and then see them all when i zoom.

[image]

I don't find the way to change the data point between zoomed and unzoomed state.

Anyone know if is possible? (I accept also other solution! :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), you can invoke `ChartPanel` methods to alter the zoom state.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't merge the points, I think you just want something like running average.
So you just run a window of specific width averaging values and replacing each data point with this averaged value.

The size of the window might be variable, but it depends on your actual data.