# jfreechart zooming out listener

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `jfreechart` library to plot line chart which changes dynamically, so I turned off axes autoscale. After zooming in axes autoscale remains turned off. The problem is when I zoom out, axes autoscale becomes on and it slows down my program (because it changes dynamically). How should I add listener, to turn off axes autoscale after zooming out?

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) invokes `restoreAutoBounds()` in an `ActionListener`, and you can use the `click-and-drag-left` gesture to the same effect.