# Create JFreeChart with both axes keyed numerically

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am making a chart that displays network latency and connection failure rate on graph. I am using `DefaultCategoryDataset` to store the data, but the problem is, that this dataset uses `String` for the X axis values:

```
  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );
  dataset.addValue( 15 , "Line name" , "X value" );
```

Since I render packets based on Unix time in miliseconds, it ends up looking like this:

[image: image description]

I'd like to fix it so that:

1. New values (larger timestamp) appear to the right, not left
2. X labels too close to each other are inteligently merged, as on this image:
   [image: image description]

To generate the dataset, I run over array of samples and end up with two `HashMap<String, Double>` representing average latency and failure rate. These are then assigned as follows:

```
//Latency line
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : time.entrySet())
{
  dataset.addValue(entry.getValue(), "Average ping [ms]", entry.getKey());
}
//Fail rate line
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : fail_rate.entrySet())
{
  dataset.addValue(entry.getValue()*100, "Fail rate [%]", entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Does the chart require Categories? Don't get the full scope of the data, but it seems an `XYDataset` would suffice. AFAIK The CategoryAxis will attempt to draw all labels without discrimination. Other charts - such as a NumberAxis or DateAxis are more reserved when rendering the labels.

Comment: @copeg Thank you, I'll google the things you mentioned. I used the category axis because that's what they used in some online tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of graph I think you should use a `XYDataset` with `TimeSeries`and `DateAxis`. There is one example demonstrated here:
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html

You can also use a custom `Timeline` implementation for your `DateAxis`, in particular to control the orientation of the dates (more recent to the right).
More information here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Timeline.html

Answer (score 2):

If your data does not require the use of Categories, you can use an [XYDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultXYDataset.html), and create an XY plot eg using [ChartFactory.createXYLineChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYLineChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-).

```
DefaultXYDataset ds = new DefaultXYDataset();
//generate random data as an example
double[][] data = new double[2][1000];
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
    data[0][i] = i;
    data[1][i] = (Math.random() * 100);
}
ds.addSeries("Time", data);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test", "Time", "Y-Axis", ds, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,false,false);
```

In this manner, problem (2) should take care of itself (and you could make use of the `DateAxis` class for rendering the time). For problem (1), using this type of axis you can just invert it:

```
myChart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setInverted(true);
```

Comment: See also `setVerticalTickLabels()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5522575/230513).