# Abnormal Behaviour of the Zoom In and Zoom Out Functionality of the JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have observed that the functionality of the "Zoom-In" and "Zoom-out" was implemented quite different than expected.Like for example when i do one step "Zoom-out" and then again after one step back of "Zoom-In". I couldn't see the Original graph again.

I don't see "Zoom-In" and "Zoom-out" functionality of JFreechart to be in the sync.

```
public class ChartPanelDemo {

    private static final String title = "Historical Data Graph";
    private ChartPanel chartPanel = createChart();
    private JButton ZoomX;
    private JButton ZoomY;
    private JButton Zoom;
    private JButton ZoomXOut;
    private JButton ZoomYOut;
    private JButton ZoomOut;
    private JButton originalGraph;
    private JButton xscaleInc;
    private JButton xscaleDec;
    private NumberAxis domainAxis;
    private NumberAxis rangeAxis;
    private int UNITS = 1;
    private static final int COUNT = 100;

    private JPanel panel;

    private double[][] sizeFr = { { TableLayout.FILL }, { TableLayout.FILL } };

    public ChartPanelDemo() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(title);

        panel = new JPanel();
        f.setTitle(title);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        f.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true); 
        // chartPanel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(true);
        // chartPanel.setVerticalAxisTrace(true);
        chartPanel.setZoomInFactor(0.9);
        chartPanel.setZoomOutFactor(0.9);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panel.add(createTrace());
        panel.add(createDate());
        panel.add(createZoom());
        panel.add(createZoomOutX());
        panel.add(createZoomOutY());
        panel.add(createZoomOut());
        panel.add(toOriginalGraph());
        panel.add(AutoScaleDecXaxis());
        //panel.add(AutoScaleDecXaxis());
        f.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }



    private JSpinner AutoScaleDecXaxis() {
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(
                new SpinnerNumberModel(UNITS, 1, COUNT, 1));
            spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    JSpinner s = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
                    Number n = (Number) s.getValue();
                    domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(n.intValue()));
                }
            });
            return spinner;
    }

    private JButton toOriginalGraph() {
        originalGraph = new JButton(new AbstractAction("RestoreGraph") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chartPanel.restoreAutoBounds();
            }

        });
        return originalGraph;
    }

    private JButton createZoomOut() {
        ZoomOut = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ZoomOut") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ZoomOut.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_OUT_BOTH_COMMAND);
                ZoomOut.addActionListener(chartPanel);

            }

        });
        return ZoomOut;
    }

    private JButton createZoomOutY() {
        ZoomYOut = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ZoomOutY") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ZoomYOut.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_OUT_RANGE_COMMAND);
                ZoomYOut.addActionListener(chartPanel);
            }

        });
        return ZoomYOut;
    }

    private JButton createZoomOutX() {
        ZoomXOut = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ZoomOutX") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ZoomXOut.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_OUT_DOMAIN_COMMAND);
                ZoomXOut.addActionListener(chartPanel);
            }
        });
        return ZoomXOut;
    }

    private JButton createTrace() {
        ZoomX = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ZoomInX") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ZoomX.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_IN_DOMAIN_COMMAND);
                ZoomX.addActionListener(chartPanel);
                // chartPanel.restoreAutoBounds();
            }
        });
        return ZoomX;
    }

    private JButton createDate() {
        ZoomY = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ZoomInY") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ZoomY.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_IN_RANGE_COMMAND);
                ZoomY.addActionListener(chartPanel);
            }
        });
        return ZoomY;
    }

    private JButton createZoom() {
        Zoom = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Zoom") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Zoom.setActionCommand(chartPanel.ZOOM_IN_BOTH_COMMAND);
                Zoom.addActionListener(chartPanel);
            }
        });
        return Zoom;
    }

    private ChartPanel createChart() {
        XYDataset roiData = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(roiData);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xBBBBDD));
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        XYSplineRenderer r = new XYSplineRenderer(20);
        plot.setRenderer(r);
        r.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        domainAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        domainAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

        return new ChartPanel(chart);
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Historical Data", // chart
                                                                                // title
                "X", // x axis label
                "Y", // y axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
                );
        return chart;

    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First");
        series1.add(1.0, 1.0);
        series1.add(2.0, 4.0);
        series1.add(3.0, 3.0);
        series1.add(4.0, 5.0);
        series1.add(5.0, 5.0);
        series1.add(6.0, 7.0);
        series1.add(7.0, 7.0);
        series1.add(8.0, 8.0);
        XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Second");
        series2.add(1.0, 5.0);
        series2.add(2.0, 7.0);
        series2.add(3.0, 6.0);
        series2.add(4.0, 8.0);
        series2.add(5.0, 4.0);
        series2.add(6.0, 4.0);
        series2.add(7.0, 2.0);
        series2.add(8.0, 1.0);

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);

        return dataset;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChartPanelDemo cpd = new ChartPanelDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Problem2: After two clicks on ZoomInX 
[image]

And again after two clicks on ZoomOutX(Which is the original graph)
[image]

But Again after two clicks on ZoomInX I see the graph a different one, not as the first image in this question which should be.
[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with the sample code i tried with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example appears to be mixing the two approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337259/230513), invoking the chart panel's handler from within your own `actionPerformed()` implementation. While the chart panel handlers are reusable, they are not re-entrant. Instead, use the chart panel's implementation directly. The example below focuses on two buttons to zoom the domain in and out:

```
toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom In X", ZOOM_IN_DOMAIN_COMMAND));
toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom Out X", ZOOM_OUT_DOMAIN_COMMAND));
…
private JButton createButton(String name, String command) {
    final JButton b = new JButton(name);
    b.setActionCommand(command);
    b.addActionListener(chartPanel);
    return b;
}
```

After clicking <kbd>Zoom In X</kbd>:

[image: after zoom in x]

After clicking <kbd>Zoom Out X</kbd>:

[image: after zoom out x]

This complete example re-factors the `createButton()` method to exercise the available zoom handlers and illustrates using a [`JToolBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Year;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import static org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel.*;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337259/230513 */
public class ZoomDemo {

    private static final String TITLE = "Return On Investment";
    private final ChartPanel chartPanel = createChart();

    public ZoomDemo() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(TITLE);
        f.setTitle(TITLE);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        f.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom In", ZOOM_IN_BOTH_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom In X", ZOOM_IN_DOMAIN_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom In Y", ZOOM_IN_RANGE_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom Out", ZOOM_OUT_BOTH_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom Out X", ZOOM_OUT_DOMAIN_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Zoom Out Y", ZOOM_OUT_RANGE_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Reset", ZOOM_RESET_BOTH_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Reset X", ZOOM_RESET_DOMAIN_COMMAND));
        toolBar.add(createButton("Reset Y", ZOOM_RESET_RANGE_COMMAND));
        panel.add(toolBar);
        f.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String name, String command) {
        final JButton b = new JButton(name);
        b.setActionCommand(command);
        b.addActionListener(chartPanel);
        return b;
    }

    private ChartPanel createChart() {
        XYDataset roiData = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            TITLE, "Date", "Value", roiData, true, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer =
            (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        currency.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(currency);
        return new ChartPanel(chart);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        tsc.addSeries(createSeries("Projected", 200));
        tsc.addSeries(createSeries("Actual", 100));
        return tsc;
    }

    private TimeSeries createSeries(String name, double scale) {
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            series.add(new Year(2016 + i), Math.pow(2, i) * scale);
        }
        return series;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZoomDemo cpd = new ZoomDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my example? If you have taken my example buttons are not working on first click. and also i see strange behavior of Zoomin and ZoomOut functionality which was my question. but when i removed this two lines of code  chartPanel.setZoomInFactor(0.9);
 chartPanel.setZoomOutFactor(0.9); ZoomIn and ZoomOut functionality is working fine as expected, but still with some problems which i explained in my question with title problem2.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that; the chart panel handlers are reusable but not re-entrant. My example focuses on the error seen in yours. Try updating your handlers as I've shown.

Comment: any clue for this newer question posted?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711618/how-can-i-have-negative-and-positive-axis-using-jfreechart?noredirect=1#comment70618972_41711618

Comment: any clue to this question on how to proceed ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998840/how-can-i-have-the-time-on-x-axis-and-control-the-scaling-value-on-a-button-clic