# Show newest inserted values in chart with TimeSeriesCollection when zoomed

Tags: jfreechart

I have such like a live chart realized with JFreeChart. The x-axis shows the time and there are several TimeSeriesCollections in the chart. If the a value is added to the TimeSeries the charts updates and shows the value only if it is not zoomed. Is there a possibility in the zoomed mode to show automatically new values (means to keep the zoom range and jump to the right).

Thanks
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution:

```
this.chart.addChangeListener((ChartChangeEvent cce) -> {
        if (scrollToNewest) {
            Number max = DatasetUtilities.findMaximumDomainValue(this.plot.getDataset(0));
            ValueAxis va = this.plot.getDomainAxis();
            Range r = va.getRange();
            double curUpperBound = r.getUpperBound();
            double diff = max.doubleValue() - curUpperBound;
            Range newR = new Range(r.getLowerBound() + diff, r.getUpperBound() + diff);
            va.setRange(newR);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Additional zoom actions are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544007/230513).