# How can I graph values that are incredibly small in Java?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Basically I am attempting to use JFreeChart right now to graph some values. The only problem is that the values are incredibly minuscule, e.g 7.069781E-13. I believe these values are too small for JFreeChart to display. How can I display these small values visually in Java in a line chart format?

It looks like this currently:

[image: Mine]

And I want to make it look similar to this:

[image: Exmaple]

Comment: Did you try setting the y axis range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around.
I simply multiplied all the values by a factor of 100 so the graph now looks similar to the one in the example. I will include a disclaimer in the legend saying the chart has been multiplied by a factor to clearly see the line chart.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider these alternative:

- Invoke `setRange()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513), to expand the *y* axis in the area of interest.
- Add suitable controls, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544007/230513), to control *y* zoom.
- Advise users how to use the mouse for zoom control, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151032/230513).